# Pandas TimeSeries Analysis

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe, which looks like this:

[image]

Some of the domains are "Uninstalled" while some are not. Some of them have "Recurring charge activated", some not. I would like to get 3 groups:

1. Domains which are currently installed and have "Recurring charge activated" (Next to "Recurring charge activated" Billing on contains the date.)
2. Domains which are currently installed and don't have "Recurring charge activated" (these domains don't have this entry at all.)
3. Domains which were uninstalled.

- for the first and third list of domains I need to calculate the number of months "Recurring charge" was active.

Any suggestion would help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Df[Df[colname] == "uninstalled"  & other condition similar to first one]     to get all the groups you need.

Comment: Thank you vishal for your answer. What would you advise about calculating months of active recurring charge?